# Add attribute of type Date to shapefile using OGR

Tags: ogr, date

can anyone tell me how to add an attribute of type Date during a shapefile creation?

For Integer works fine using the following code:

```
Layer1.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('NumberIndv', ogr.OFTInteger))
```

The same for String and Real, changing the type to `ogr.OFTString` or `ogr.OFTReal`.

What should I use for Date type?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry, I'm a newbie in GDAL/OGR and in fact I found this link: http://www.gdal.org/ogr__core_8h.html#a787194bea637faf12d61643124a7c9fc.

Comment: No problem and don't worry, you're now more experienced in GDAL/OGR than I am! But will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ogr.OFTDate` to create a new *date-type* field so your line would look something like:

```
Layer1.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('DATE', ogr.OFTDate))
```

This and other OGR field types are documented in

http://www.gdal.org/ogr__core_8h.html#a787194bea637faf12d61643124a7c9fc